# MySQL python query for extracting data from columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql

---

I need some help to construct a query in MySQL, to output some data.
My table is named "data" and is containig three columns "col1" in wich are the dates, but not in sql format, "col2" contains times, and "col3" contains values that i need to output. So how would i construct a query that would first check col1 for specific date and then check col2 for specific time range between those date in first column, and then return the values of the selection.

I have tried it like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `col 1`='6.9.2015' AND TIME(`col 2`) BETWEEN '23:00:00' AND '23:59:00'"
```

but my query returns also a date of 7.9.2015.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `=` to compare strings. Replace `=` with `LIKE` in order to do string comparisons.

Also, if you want to just return `col3` as your output, replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT 'col3'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. but it didn't work so i will try to explain it one more time. col1 contains dates, col2 contains times, col3 contains values...I wish to query for the highest value in col3 between time 23:00 and 23:59 in col2 of the specific date in col3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if you only want the highest entry, you add: ORDER BY col3 DESC LIMIT 1; to the end of the query to order it, then limit the it so it only gives you the highest value.

Comment: Sure this could work, but my problem is when i run the query i get as result a couple of outputs from specific date and a couple from another date.

Comment: Could it be a problem with your quotation marks. I notice in the printed code that the quotes around col1, col2 and data are not standard single quotes?